# Strange abline behavior when inverting X and Y

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I'm trying to do a regression line with 2 variables, WMC and BUG

When BUG is the X axis, the regression line seems perfect.
However, when BUG is the Y axis and WMC the X axis, the line behaves strangely, it doesn't seem to fit the plot at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
reg1 <- lm (WMC ~ BUG)
plot(BUG,WMC)
abline(reg1)
```

[image: plot1]

```
reg1 <- lm (BUG ~ WMC)
plot(WMC,BUG)
abline(reg1)
```

[image: plot2]

Yeah, I'm a stats noob.

Comment: can you provide us with the data?

Comment: Sure! There you go I uploaded it! http://speedy.sh/XSZyT/ant17NORM.csv Just right click the link and -> Download linked file as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the rationale for your models at the moment: there is nothing wrong with how the lines are plotted. The reason why the lines seem to fit differently to the plot is because you are estimating two different models.

So let's start with your first model where you regress `wmc` on `bug`

```
m1<-lm(wmc~bug,df);summary(m1)
Call:
lm(formula = wmc ~ bug, data = df)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.17555 -0.55069  0.00892  0.46091  2.23740 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.93699    0.03057   63.37   <2e-16***
bug          0.84808    0.05926   14.31   <2e-16*** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7508 on 743 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2161,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.215 
F-statistic: 204.8 on 1 and 743 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

This model tells us that when regressing `wmc` on `bug` that a unit increase in `bug` corresponds with a 0.85 increase in `wmc` (I don't know what the original units of your measurement are). This is reflected in the plot if you look at the intercept value and the slope of the line over one unit increase of `bug`:

[image]

Now in the second model you do the opposite. You regress `bug` on `wmc`.

```
m2<-lm(bug~wmc,df);summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = bug ~ wmc, data = df)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.74635 -0.26947 -0.09287  0.14058  1.67470 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.31717    0.04077  -7.779 2.44e-14***
wmc          0.25477    0.01780  14.310  < 2e-16***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4115 on 743 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2161,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.215 
F-statistic: 204.8 on 1 and 743 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So in this case a one unit increase in `wmc` corresponds with a 0.25 increase in `bug`. Which is also reflected in the plot, notice again the value of the intercept and slope of the line with regard to a one unit increase in `wmc` in this case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just got confused by the look of it I guess!